# How crash in one thread affects other threads.

Tags: android, c, multithreading, linux-device-driver, system-calls

I have a program with 2 threads.

- Thread1: In IOCTL call (interacting with driver)
- Thread2: Doing other stuff where SIGSEGV came.

In this case does Thread1 completes execution of ioctl call or thread is stopped in between executing kernel code?

If possible, please provide answer in Windows, linux and android context (Where debuggerd attaches to process using ptrace to create tombstones).

Comment: Please detail the steps you took to investigate this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for Linux: I am assuming that the process will terminate as part of thread 2 handling SIGSEGV.  In Linux, a thread cannot normally terminate as such while it is in kernel mode, though the system call code may (e.g. if it is in a so-called interruptible wait) notice the process termination and exit early.  Thread 1 will terminate once it returns.

I am not familiar with Android from a development perspective, but my understanding is that processes set up a handler for a number of signals which wakes the debuggerd daemon, which in turn attaches to the process handling the signal with ptrace and dumps various bits of process state.  I would expect this to be able to happen before thread 1 returns from the system call.

Comment: Thanks for taking time in answering this. Can you please provide any citation for _"thread cannot normally terminate as such while it is in kernel mode"_

Comment: If the kernel code being executed explicitly terminates the thread (example, the _exit system call) or another kernel thread does that then of course the thread can terminate in kernel mode.  Otherwise: I don't have a good citation to provide, but take a look at kernel/exit.c and kernel/thread.c, specifically do_group_exit(), which is "called by fatal signals".  This sends a kill signal to all threads in the group, and signals are processed in user mode (e.g. after finishing a system call) not in kernel mode.  Threads in interruptible sleeps are woken up.